# How to parse xml data from clob in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, xml-parsing

The xml is:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:abcs="http://www.avea.com.tr/om/ABCS_BSCS_ASSET_OPERATIONS" xmlns:ave="http://www.avea.com.tr/AveaFrameWork" xmlns:ebs="http://www.avea.com.tr/om/EBS_COMMITMENT_ASSET_OPERATIONS"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ebs:EbsRetrieveProbableCommitmentPenaltiesResponse>
                <ave:ResponseHeader>
                    <ave:RequestId>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ave:GUID>?</ave:GUID>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ave:ListOfTransId>
                            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                            <ave:TransId>
                                <ave:SystemName>?</ave:SystemName>
                                <ave:ExtendedValue>?</ave:ExtendedValue>
                            </ave:TransId>
                        </ave:ListOfTransId>
                    </ave:RequestId>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ave:TimeStampDateTime>?</ave:TimeStampDateTime>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ave:ElapsedTime>?</ave:ElapsedTime>
                </ave:ResponseHeader>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <abcs:ResponseBody>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <abcs:listOfCommitmentPenalty>
                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                        <abcs:commitmentPenalty>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:commitmentName>asddsfdsf dsfsdf</abcs:commitmentName>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:startDate>2014-11-12T16:06:05.664+02:00</abcs:startDate>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:endDate>2015-11-12T16:06:05.664+02:00</abcs:endDate>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:totalPeriod>365</abcs:totalPeriod>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:remainingPeriod>120</abcs:remainingPeriod>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:penaltyAmount>1200</abcs:penaltyAmount>
                        </abcs:commitmentPenalty>
                        <abcs:commitmentPenalty>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:commitmentName>asdasd asdasd</abcs:commitmentName>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:startDate>2013-04-10T16:06:05.664+02:00</abcs:startDate>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:endDate>2015-04-10T16:06:05.664+02:00</abcs:endDate>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:totalPeriod>720</abcs:totalPeriod>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:remainingPeriod>30</abcs:remainingPeriod>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <abcs:penaltyAmount>500</abcs:penaltyAmount>
                        </abcs:commitmentPenalty>
                    </abcs:listOfCommitmentPenalty>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <abcs:totalPenaltyAmount>1700</abcs:totalPenaltyAmount>
                </abcs:ResponseBody>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <ave:ResultStatus>
                    <ave:resultCode>0</ave:resultCode>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ave:resultMessageList>
                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                        <ave:resultMessage>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <ave:resultMessageId>?</ave:resultMessageId>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <ave:resultMessageSubId>?</ave:resultMessageSubId>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <ave:resultStringCode>?</ave:resultStringCode>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <ave:resultDescription>?</ave:resultDescription>
                        </ave:resultMessage>
                    </ave:resultMessageList>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ave:KeyValuePairList>
                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                        <ave:KeyValuePair>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <ave:key>?</ave:key>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <ave:value>?</ave:value>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <ave:data_type>?</ave:data_type>
                        </ave:KeyValuePair>
                    </ave:KeyValuePairList>
                </ave:ResultStatus>
            </ebs:EbsRetrieveProbableCommitmentPenaltiesResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Sql:

```
select atts.att1,atts.att2,my_table.PL_IN
    from my_table
         , xmltable(
                xmlnamespaces(
                    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soapenv"
                       , 'http://www.avea.com.tr/om/ABCS_BSCS_ASSET_OPERATIONS' as "abcs"
                      , 'http://www.avea.com.tr/AveaFrameWork' as "ave"
                      ,'http://www.avea.com.tr/om/EBS_COMMITMENT_ASSET_OPERATIONS' as "ebs")
                ,'/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/soapenv:Body/abcs:ResponseBody/abcs:listOfCommitmentPenalty/abcs:commitmentPenalty'
                passing xmltype(my_table.PL_IN)
                columns
                    att1 varchar2 (20) path 'abcs:commitmentName',
                    att2 number path 'abcs:totalPeriod') atts
```

I am trying to parse clob xml data in oracle no rows return. In the  sql I define namespaces and  parse xml, but it does not work. I've tried almost all the solutions I've done in Google, but it did not. Is there anyone that can help me or Anyone suggest for this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is incorrect. `soapenv:Body` is at the same level as `soapenv:Header`, which is an empty tag. You've also missed out the `ebs:EbsRetrieveProbableCommitmentPenaltiesResponse` node at the top of the body.

So the XPath should start:

```
'/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ebs:EbsRetrieveProbableCommitmentPenaltiesResponse/abcs:ResponseBody/...
```

With just that change your query gets:

```
ATT1                       ATT2 PL_IN                                                                           
-------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
asddsfdsf dsfsdf            365 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmln
asdasd asdasd               720 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmln
```